# How to access Koa context (and koa-session) from Apollo resolvers?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, koa, apollo-server-koa

Given the following Koa application initialization :

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  ...processSchema(schemas),
  ...graphqlConfig,
  cors: false,   // already present with Koa
  context: ctx => {
    console.log( "*** 2", ctx.session );
    // -> *** 2 undefined
  }
});

const app = new Koa();

const serverHttp = app
  .use(cors(CORS_CONFIG))
  .use(session(SESSION_CONFIG, app))
  .use(async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log( "*** 1", ctx.session );
    // *** 1 Session { ...session object }

    await next();

    if (!ctx.body) {
      ctx.throw(404);
    }
  })
  .use(koaBody())
  .use(apolloServer.getMiddleware())
  .listen(port)
;
```

As you can see, making any GraphQL query will output

```
*** 1 Session { ...session object }
*** 2 undefined
```

Showing that Apollo does not receive the context, neither the session.

1. Is it possible to have access to the session from `context` function?
2. Is it possible to have access to the session from a resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to access `session` from the `context` function, and here's the way to do it:

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: (req) => {
    const { session } = req.ctx;

    // return an object with whatever properties you 
    // need to be accessible inside resolvers as `context`
    return {
      userSession: session
    }
  }
})
```

Then, inside your `resolver`, you can access it the following way:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: (parent, args, context) {
      const { userSession } = context;
      const books = [...];

      return books;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah! I was so close! Cheers!